# how to update MongoDB doc field only if value not set in golang

Tags: mongodb, go

I have a collection with docs like:

```
{ID: xxx, firstCreateDate: xxx, isActive: false}
```

1. I want to find all the docs where `isActive = false`, then update `isActive` to true, and also update `firstCreateDate` to current date if not set before. I'm not sure how to conditionally update filed firstCreateDate. Couldn't get the conditionally update working right now. Got
   `firstCreateDate = {$cond:[{"firstCreateDate":{"$exists":false}}, "$firstCreateDate", newdata]}`
2. I also want to use a custom function to generate a new field internalID based on original `ID` field. I tried to use `UpdateMany()`, but seems like there is no way to get the value and calculate the new value using your own function. I'm thinking about use `Find()` to find all docs, then decode it, and then update docs one by one based on id. Is there any better solution for this?

This is what I have now:

```
filter := bson.M{"isActive": false}
update := bson.M{"set": bson.M{"isActive": true, "firstCreateDate": bson.M{
  "$cond": bson.A{
    bson.M{"firstCreateDate", bson.M{"$exists", false}},
    "$firstCreateDate",
    newDate,
  }
}}}

collection.UpdateByID(
  context.Background(),
  id,
  update,
)
```

I'm using [mongo-driver](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo) lib, anyone can help

Comment: I dont understand your second requirement with UUID.  What are you actually trying to do with the current _id?  Maybe a specific before and after example?

Comment: I'm trying to calculate the UUID based on current _id and store the value in a new field

Comment: What the reason for that when Mongo generates an ObjectID that essentially serves the same purpose.

Comment: I'm simplifying my use case in the question above. The "original id" I have is a root level object id, the new id I'm trying to generate is the id for a nested object.

Comment: What happens if `isActive: true` and `firstCreateDate` is not set? Do you still want to set the date?

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with the first part.

First you just want to find where `isActive` is false and where `firstCreateDate` is not set. If the field exist and is just Null, take a look at https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/

```
res, err := collection.UpdateMany(ctx, bson.M{
    "isActive": false,
    "firstCreateDate": bson.M{"$exists": false},
}, bson.D{
    {"$set", bson.M{"isActive": true}},
    {"$set", bson.M{"firstCreateDate": newDate}},
})
```

Answer (score -1):

A few things..

1. If you use the _id default it will be generated for you and you can extract the creation date directly from there.  This is mainly a preference question honestly whether you want to see a clear date in your document for readability or just grab what exists in the generated _id.
2. I have not had to solve for the second requirement before.  Personally, I would never generate ObjectIds in sub documents unless they were a foreign key to another collection.  If that was the case, I would generate the ObjectID in the the other collection first and then associate that _id with this collection by inserting the reference.
3. You can use the aggregation pipeline in updateMany statements. `$set` takes mostly the same syntax as the projection operator.

Here is the updateMany that will solve your first question. It uses the mongosh syntax but you should be able to convert the logic to go.

```
db.collection.updateMany(
    { isActive: false }, 
    [{$set: {
        firstCreateDate: {
            $ifNull: [
                '$firstCreateDate',
                ISODate('2022-03-26T03:52:45.240Z')
            ]
        },
        isActive: {
            $toBool: true
        },
        _idExtractDate: {
            $convert: {
                input: '$_id',
                to: 'date'
            }
        }
    }}]
);
```